# python; struct, how to pack a newline

Tags: python, struct

```
print(pack('c', b'x0a'))
print(pack('c', b'\n'))
print(pack('c', '\n'))
```

all lead to

```
struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1
```

---

```
x = pack('s', b'\n')
for i in x: print(i)
```

leads to `10`, so that is possibly on the right track, but I am trying to get it to show me `x0a`.

Comment: I think you forgot a backslash: `struct.pack('c', b'\x0a')`. `struct.pack('c', b'\n')` also works fine for me in both Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two versions should work fine:

```
from struct import pack

print(pack('c', b'\x0a'))
print(pack('c', b'\n'))
```

Which would display:

```
b'\n'
b'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you can't have a character format that's longer than one byte. This means, as mentioned by Michael Foukarakis, you need to add a backslash character, `\`, to `x0a` in this line:

> ```
> print(pack('c', b'x0a'))
> ```

Which means this line would become this:

```
print(pack('c', b'\x0a'))
```